# How to update state when routing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I have the following button.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);
<Button component={RouterLink}
        to="/cr-journey"
        onClick={() => setSearch(true)}
        fullWidth>Search
    </Button>
```

I would like to update the state when the button is click. Probably because the button will route to a different component then the state will not be updated.

```
const xxx = useCallback(() => { dispatch(journeyAction.journeyFilterData(search));}, [dispatch,search]);
useEffect(() => { xxx() });
```

How can I make sure useEffect will update the state when clicking the button?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When route changes basically component unmounts.And you cannot control local state of unmounted component.

But you can update redux state when component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {

   return () => // your dispatch function  

}, []);
```

But if component does not unmount just paste update function in `useEffect` without return keyword.

```
 useEffect(() => {

      dispatch(someFunc()); // when search updates this will be call
    
 }, [search]);
```

Comment: I was going to recommend an `onClick` function which updated the state and then triggered a redirect via `history.push()`, but I like your answer better.  A `useEffect` clean-up function is genius!

Comment: Hi Randall, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately its still not working for me.  Can you please elaborate on your answer. From what I understand I should use the first option since the component is unmount ?

Comment: @angus if your component unmount you need to use first option.Change redux state when component unmounts.If it's still mounted when page redirected use `useEffect` with array dependencies.

Comment: @angus if you still can't understand, or it's not working send me sandbox with your  minimalistic code logic.

Comment: @angus Because component unmount local state does not change and that's why you redux state is remains same .Here the working example that state changes https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-wave-6kdv4 This code is super ugly.I hope your doing this in learning purposes. And this is not a prod. code. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I can see that you are updating the store directly. It this a recommended approach ? I mean rather then using useEffect ? Also I am curious about your feedback about the code example ? why do you think its not prod level. Thanks